# Drupal 8 translate custom menu link?

Tags: drupal, menu, translation, translate, drupal-8

In drupal 8, when I try to check the 'custom menu link' checkbox at `admin/config/regional/content-language`, after validation the checkbox remains unchecked.. 
No errors or warnings on page or in my dblog.. Have cleared cache multiple times and ran `composer update` to make sure all modules and core are up to date.

Am I doing something wrong to translate my menu, or will i have to make multiple menu's for each language the good old drupal 7 way?

Running Drupal 8.1.2 atm. 
`**`**edit**`**` updated to drupal 8.1.3, same problem

Answer (score 1):

Apparently when you check the 'custom menu link' checkbox, a new item is added with ajax at the bottom of the page to chose what fields of the menu item you wish to translate without the checkbox being checked yet.. Apparently you need to check those extra fields also before validating, else the checkbox won't get checked.